# setting aspect ratio of plot region != 1 within call to layout() in R

Tags: r, layout, graph, aspect-ratio

In the base graphics package for R, a unitary aspect ratio for a plot can be set within a `layout()` call using the `respect = TRUE` argument.  How can other aspect ratios be set within `layout()`? `?layout` says that relative widths can be specified with numeric values, but doesn't say relative to what. Googling doesn't find me any examples that use this capability, and a few shot-in-the-dark guesses such as `layout(matrix(c(1,2,3)), widths = 0.7)` or `widths = c(0.7, 0.5, 0.7)` have not been successful. I have found a few suggestions on how to do this in ggplot2, but am curious about this specific capability of `layout()` in particular.

TL;DR: ?layout says that relative widths can be specified with numeric values in the `widths` argument.  How does this work?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete, reproducible example here? It's unclear what your goal is.

Comment: I've edited a bit, @MrFlick, hopefully that clarifies.  I'm not sure how to write a reproducible example for an argument I don't know how to use.

Comment: With widths are for each of the columns in your layout. Each row/column has a single width and the plots are rendered inside each cell. When you have `layout(matrix(c(1,2,3))`, you only have one column so the widths are basically ignored. The widths are relative to each other. So if you set `widths=c(1,3,2)` the middle column will be three times the width of the first. You basically take `widths/sum(widths)` to assign a proportion of the available width to each column.